# Convert from string to int C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on C# Windows Form application, and I want to create search form with two combo box, which contain two fields
-Genres
-Author
Genres and Author need to be load from database, and I create a function that loads Genres and Author, but when I load Genres from db I get error 
"Cannot convert from string to int"

I try

```
string Genres = dr.GetString("Genres");
this.Genres.Items.Add(Genres);




void FillDropDown()
        {
            string constring = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Libary;Integrated Security=True";
            string Query = "Select * from Book ";
            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string Genres = dr.GetString("Genres");
                    this.Genres.Items.Add(Genres);


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `this.Genres.Items`?

Comment: [Genres]    NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,

Comment: You might want to look into using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) as it handles a lot of the boiler plate code you have to write when using ADO.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) takes an integer index, not a string column name.  Use [`GetOrdinal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal?view=netframework-4.7.2) to find the index for a given column name.

```
string Genres = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Genres"));
```

Comment: @Radial  Or `string Genres = dr["Genres"]?.ToString();`

Comment: @Jimi Yes, though you don't need the `?` because it will never return `null` instead it would return `DBNull` if the value from the query is null.